# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home3/fireball/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/page.php on line 13

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Not sure whats wrong. I have looked and guess its php thats doing it. Ive seen this posted but cant find a fix.

its hard to post on here' * The template for displaying all pages

```
*
* This is the template that displays all pages by default.
* Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages and that
* other 'pages' on your WordPress site will use a different template.
*
* @package WordPress
* @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
* @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0




<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all pages
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages and that
 * other 'pages' on your WordPress site will use a different template.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */
 <div id="main-content" class="main-content">
<?php
if ( is_front_page() && twentyfourteen_has_featured_posts() ) {
    // Include the featured content template.
    get_template_part( 'featured-content' );
}
?>
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

        <?php
            // Start the Loop.
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                // Include the page content template.
                get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );

                // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the    comment     template.
                if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
                    comments_template();
                }
            endwhile;
        ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
<?php get_sidebar( 'content' ); ?>
</div><!-- #main-content -->

<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

Comment: What’s the `<div id="main-content" class="main-content">` doing inside the `<?php` block?

Answer (score 1):

Close out the php tag on the last line of the initial block of commented out code.  It should look like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all pages
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages and that
 * other 'pages' on your WordPress site will use a different template.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */ ?>
 <div id="main-content" class="main-content">
```